# How can I write a command line shell to capture 'UP' key to get historic input?

Tags: c++, c, shell, command-line

I want to write a command line shell for a background program, and in witch I can type some commands. I want to add a feature like the bash (or other shell-like) ---'UP' key to get the historic input. How can I capture the 'UP' key was pressed?

If I just use `std::getline(std::cin, line)` I can't get the 'UP' key or other function key, ie. Ctrl+w to delete a word of the input line.

Comment: There is a "getline library", which is a set of C functionality that allow you to edit/record history/etc on the input for your program. Alternatively, you will have to read raw input and handle keyboard input yourself...

Comment: There was a [related (though different) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505947/how-to-make-command-history-in-console-application/18506211#18506211) today, which might be of interest.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Your suggestion is very useful, it should be an answer rather than a commant. I use GNU readline library now. http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `readline` function that supports history and line editing, etc.

In basic mode it does reading of line, etc. If you want to add hooks, you can make it expand commands when pressing `tab` or similar.

This is what your typical shell in Linux uses.

Documentation here:
http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html

An example here:
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_48.html

Main project page:
http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `kbhit()` to get Keyboard Arrow Keys

Comment: Does it work for all compilers? [see](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use ncurses library, see [sample program](http://books.google.pl/books?id=Htff8VRO-UEC&pg=PA346&dq=ncurses+key_up+key_down&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iikfUubbCMrQsgbjn4CoCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ncurses%20key_up%20key_down&f=false):

```
#include<ncurses.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int ch;
    initscr();  //initialize the ncurses data structures

    keypad(stdscr,TRUE); //enable special keys capturing

    ch=getch();

    if(ch==KEY_UP)
        std::cout << "Key up pressed!" << std::endl;
}
```